# Calculate is times between times

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function that excepts 2 parameters arrays of times and return true or false if the second array between one of the times of the first array:

```
function calculateIsBetween(workTimes, breakTimes) {
 // ... ... ...
}
```

example 1:

```
calculateIsBetween(
[
  {entryTime: '12:00', exitTime: '13:00'},
  {entryTime: '14:00', exitTime: '15:00'}
],


[
  {startBreak: '12:05', endBreak: '12:10'},
  {startBreak: '12:25', endBreak: '12:30'}
]
)
```

function returns true because breaks between at least one of the entry time and exit time.

example 2:

```
calculateIsBetween(
[
  {entryTime: '12:00', exitTime: '13:00'},
  {entryTime: '14:00', exitTime: '15:00'}
],
   

[
  {startBreak: '16:05', endBreak: '18:10'},
  {startBreak: '12:25', endBreak: '12:30'}
]
)
```

function returns false because breaks not between at least one of the entry time and exit time.

p.s
function also needs to take care about overnight times.

I tried something with moment but it doesn't work well.

May you can help me

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed question? What have you tried to solve your problem, as it stands your code is partial and your problem cannot be recreated. Is it safe to assume that for any of the work times, all of the break times must be between the ```entryTime``` and ```exitTime```? More information would be required in this case to help you with your problem as you have also mentioned overnight times, assuming a consecutive day, from one day into the next. Keep us updated once question changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will attempt to break down my code, hopefully it is written well enough to be self explanatory. First I need to create an array of allowed ranges for breaks. Each item in the array will have a max for the hours, and a max for the minutes. I use `.map` to create the array of max - min values from the work times argument passed.

My next line returns the boolean return from a `.every` test method placed on the `breakTimes` array. The test that every item in the array must pass is a function which first grabs the start and end values for hour and minute. This test returns true if even one set from the allowed ranges allows the break times.

I did not understand what you meant by taking the next day into consideration, there was no data for the day in the examples given. This should be a good stepping off point though.

If you have any questions about the code, please ask

```js
function calculateIsBetween(workTimes, breakTimes) {
  const allowedRanges = workTimes.map(({entryTime, exitTime}) => {
    const [hMin, mMin] = entryTime.split(":");
    const [hMax, mMax] = exitTime.split(":");
    return {hMin, hMax, mMin, mMax};
  });
  return breakTimes.every(({startBreak, endBreak}) => {
    const [hStart, mStart] = startBreak.split(":");
    const [hEnd, mEnd] = endBreak.split(":");
    return allowedRanges.some(({hMin, hMax, mMin, mMax}) => {
      if (
        hStart < hMin ||
        hEnd > hMax
      ) return false;
      if (
        hStart > hMin &&
        hEnd < hMax
      ) return true;
      if (
        (hStart == hMin && mStart < mMin) ||
        (hEnd == hMax && mEnd > mMax)
      ) return false;
      return true;
    });
  });
}
console.log(
  calculateIsBetween(
    [
      {entryTime: '12:00', exitTime: '13:00'},
      {entryTime: '14:00', exitTime: '15:00'}
    ],
    [
      {startBreak: '12:05', endBreak: '12:10'},
      {startBreak: '12:25', endBreak: '12:30'}
    ]
  )
); //returns true
console.log(
  calculateIsBetween(
    [
      {entryTime: '12:00', exitTime: '13:00'},
      {entryTime: '14:00', exitTime: '15:00'}
    ],
    [
      {startBreak: '16:05', endBreak: '18:10'},
      {startBreak: '12:25', endBreak: '12:30'}
    ]
  )
); //returns false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```